# How to retrieve data from an IList created from an API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm extracting data from an API booked system into C#, using http://jsonutils.com/ and Postman to help me create the classes.

I can extract the data from the class but not out of the Ilist. Any advice?

The below is an example of the the classes and the Ilist that is generated with in. I can extract data from the Session class but not the Event class.

```
//events field
public class Session
{
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public int companyID { get; set; }
    public object rdPartyID { get; set; }
    public int eventCatID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string endTime { get; set; }
    public object notes { get; set; }
    public int capacity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int spacesReserved { get; set; }
    public int spacesSold { get; set; }
    public int spacesAvailable { get; set; }
    public int orderCount { get; set; }
    public int reservationCount { get; set; }
    public string sessionType { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int eventCatID { get; set; }
    public object rdPartyID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
    public object soldOutMessage { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string sessionType { get; set; }
    public int allowSalesDuringSessions { get; set; }
    public int yellowThreshold { get; set; }
    public int amberThreshold { get; set; }
    public int redThreshold { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int navOrder { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public object terms { get; set; }   
    public string staffSalesCutoffPointAfterSessionStart { get; set; }
    public object staffSalesCutoffTime { get; set; }
    public int showSessionNames { get; set; }
    public int showRemainingSpaces { get; set; }
    public object capacityNotificationSpacesRemaining { get; set; }
    public object capacityNotificationMessage { get; set; }
    public int showAvailabilityColoursOnDay { get; set; }
    public int customerEditable { get; set; }
    public int amendmentCutoffHoursBeforeEvent { get; set; }
    public string amendmentChargePer { get; set; }
    public string amendmentCharge { get; set; }
    public string amendmentChargeCap { get; set; }
    public string backgroundImage { get; set; }
    public IList<Session> sessions { get; set; }
}
```

My data extraction for the basic classes is easy.

Comment: Have you tried change IList<Session> to List<Session> or Session[]?

Comment: how are you deserializing the data? can you provide an example of the json data? can you provide an example of the non-working solution (e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/)? look at the guidlies (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) provide a minimal example to replicate the issue

Comment: serializers need explicit types for deserialization, so they know what to create an instance of, but `IList<Session>` is an interface you can not create instances of it at all, so this cannot work. as @Alex-TinLe said try something like `List<Session>` instead

Comment: Thank you all,
I changed IList<Session> to List<Session> then called it with data1.sessions[1].time and it will called the desired data.
Thank you all for your help.